# what tools do you use for wall clock profiling your C++ apps?

Tags: c++, c, linux, profiling, perf

I have to profile my multithreaded C++ app and find its bottlenecks. The problem is: I need to see wall clock profile. I have used `oprofile` and `perf`. No one can provide me such information.

I have used `perf record -g -e sched:sched_stat_sleep <cmd>` but `perf record` falls with SIGFPE exception. This makes me angry.

`Valgrind` doesn't suits me because I use `fanotify_mark` syscall which is not implemented in this tool.

I'm not sure google's `perftools` can do wall clock profiling - I haven't see any info in their documentation.

Can anyone suggest? Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803930/get-gprof-to-profile-based-on-wall-clock-time ?

Comment: Not really a dupe in my opinion as it focuses on `gprof`, but one of it's answers might help indeed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9206184/694576

Comment: If you follow @alk's (Thank you!) link and beyond, you will find also http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/1741542, http://stackoverflow.com/a/927773/1741542 and http://poormansprofiler.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try PAPI http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~terpstra/using_papi/, it is an open source profiler. I normally use this profiler to measure the cache performance (e.g, misses and accesses) in some algorithms. Maybe it can be useful also for what you want.

If you have MAC, have a look on the profiler "instruments"